# How to make Context Menu Items working with UI Automation  in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, automation, contextmenu

I have real difficulties to have MenuItem visible using UISpy for UI Automation testing . The menuItems does not show up in UISpy. Assigning AutomationProperties.AutomationId properties does not help. I have no clue what can be done. I am wondering if there is a good solution to fix this issue. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you!

I tested it with this simple prototype. Please note that added button shows up in UISpy:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Grid" Width="150" Height="150" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Border x:Name="Border" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Border" 
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFE7E7E7" Height="125">

            <InputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <InputToolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="menu" >
                    <InputToolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item1" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item1" Header="Item 1" />
                    <InputToolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item2" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item2" Header="Item 2"/>
                    <InputToolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item3" Header="Item 3" />  
                </InputToolkit:ContextMenu>
            </InputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>   
        </Border>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Button1" 
        Height="25" Width="150" Content="Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to face this problem, use SilverlightSpy.